# How to get app in router files (in Node/Express app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My app.js looks like this:

```
app = express();
setup.configure(app);
//...more stuff (e.g. database setup, middleware definition, etc.)...
var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/api', api);
module.exports = app;
```

In the routes/api.js, I then have routes with middleware like this:

```
router.get('/myroute',
    app.sessionMW,
    function (req, res, next) {
        //...
    });
```

JSLint flags an error because I declare the `app` variable as global.
If I declare it with `var`, I get an error in the route because app is `undefined`. If I require the app in the routes file with `var app = require('../app')`, I get this error:

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object
>   Undefined]

I would like to properly define the app by doing

```
var app = express();
```

But how do I access the app in the routes file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to access the express 'app' object from inside a separate route file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748337/whats-the-best-way-to-access-the-express-app-object-from-inside-a-separate-ro)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just pass your `app` object in your `routes/api.js` file:

**app.js**

```
var api = require('./routes/api')(app); // pass 'app'
```

**routes/api.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {     
  ...
  router.get('/myroute', app.sessionMW, function (req, res, next) { //... });
  ...      
})
```

Answer (score 28):

According to the Express 4.x docs, you can access the app object easily through the request and response objects using `req.app` & `res.app`

> The Express application object can be referred from the [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object
>   and the [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) object as `req.app`, and `res.app`, respectively.

- [req.app](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app)

  > This property holds a reference to the instance of the Express application that is using the middleware.
- [res.app](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.app)

  > `res.app` is *identical* to the `req.app` property in the **Request** object.

code-example:

*server.js*:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('firends', 'nodejs, python');

var page = require(path.join(
    __dirname,
    'page'
));
app.use('', page);

app.listen(3000);
```

*page.js*:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/test-route', function (req, res) {
    var app = req.app; // get app object
    res.send('firends are: ' + app.get('firends')); // get firends from app
});

module.exports = router;
```

Tips:

- *server.js* and *page.js* are in the same folder.
- run with command: `node server.js`
- visit with url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/test-route`