# Express: how can I get the app from the router?

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

I know I can [get the Express `app` from inside an individual route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748337/whats-the-best-way-to-access-the-express-app-object-from-inside-a-separate-ro) with:

```
req.app
```

However I need to start a single instance of a module inside `routes/index.js`, i.e.:

```
var myModule = require('my-module')(propertyOfApp)
```

How can I get the express `app` from the [`router`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code the usage of `app` in the [router](https://github.com/strongloop/express/tree/master/lib/router). I guess you can simply pass app to the obj that uses it? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov 'simply pass app to the obj that uses it?' is exactly my question. How do I get a reference to the `app` (which was started in `app.js) in `index/routes.js`?

Comment: Well it depends what your `routes.js` looks like and how you instantiate it :) You can convert it as a function, pass app and return router: `app.use(require('./index/routes')(app));`

Comment: Thanks @AndreyPopov. I've made my router export a single function, taking propertyOfApp as a parameter. Inside routes I can then start tje module that needs propertyOfApp. Want to add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your own implementation, but what I suggested in the comments should be working:

```
// index.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    // can use app here
    // somehow create your router and do the magic, configure it as you wish
    router.get('/path', function (req, res, next) {});

    return router;
}

// app.js
// actually call the function that is returned by require,
// and when executed, the function will return your configured router
app.use(require('./index')(app));
```

p.s.
Of course this is just a sample - you can configure your router with path, and all kind of properties you wish. Cheers! :)